# How to save color to sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, random, colors

So I choose a random color.

```
Random color = new Random();
final int color2 = (Color.argb(255, color.nextInt(255),color.nextInt(255), color.nextInt(255)));
```

Then I enter it into the database

```
HashMap<String, String> colorvalues = new HashMap<String, String>();
        colorvalues.put("boxcolors", String.valueOf(color2));
        controller.insertcolorinfo(colorvalues);
        Log.d(LOGCAT, " NEW COLOR INSERTED"  + colorvalues);
```

When I check the values in logcat of my newly inserted data I get something like 
NEW COLOR INSERTED [somenumber,null,null,null]
I need to know how to insert this into the database properly so I can retrieve that saved color value later. I do see that there are four variables determining the color that make up color2 but I have no clue how to save them to the database.

Thanks

Comment: Try this way : String hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b);

Answer (score 1):

Well this is easy i have the same thing in my app. Here it goes

As the color is an `INTEGER` variable store the `color2` as per your code directly in your database declaring it as `INTEGER` instead of `VARCHAR` or any other. Now get the values using either `rawquery` or the method you are using to fetch the data from database.

I'm using `cursor` hence i use `rawquery` so here is my piece of code:

```
 int color = 0;
    Cursor colorCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT color FROM entry WHERE date='" + date + "'", null);
    if (colorCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        color = colorCursor.getInt(0);
    }
```

And then you can directly use the following like this

```
view.setBackgroundColor(color);
```